# jquery uncheck dynamic checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dynamic

I am using load() to import some html into my page which includes some checkboxes. I'd like to have a refresh button which clears any checked checkboxes but I have been unable to get this working. Please let me know what else I can try. This selector does find all checkboxes which are 'checked' but none of the functions uncheck the checkbox.

```
$('#reset_button').on('click',function() 
    {
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function()
        {
            //alert($(this).val())});
            $(this).prop('checked',false);
            $(this).attr('checked',false);
            $(this).val('off');
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        })
    }
    );
```

Conclusion note, I had to remove a class from the parent element which was styling the checkbox. the functions provided below were updating the status of the checkbox to 'unchecked' but item was not being redrawn due to styling

Comment: try `$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i,v) {
  //alert($(this).val())});
  $(v).prop('checked', false);
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the single line code that [uncheck all the checked checkboxes.](https://jsfiddle.net/Jency02/gydcj1ud/1/) *(This example illustrates both check and uncheck all checkboxes using jquery)*
  **Set `prop` of the checkbox to `false`**

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass arguments to the function to access each of the checked element and then set it checked attribute to false using

```
$(item).prop('checked', false);
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#generate').on('click', function(){
    $('#check').append('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>');
    $('#check').append('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>');
  })
  $('#reset_button').on('click',function() 
    {
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(index, item)
        {
            //alert($(this).val())});
           $(item).prop('checked',false);
        })
    }
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="generate">Generate boxes</button>
<div id="check"></div>
<button id="reset_button">Reset</button>
```

Comment: thanks for this. there must be something else wrong though as it still wont update. ive commented out my code and copied in yours. it maybe has something to do with using the load() function to insert html rather than adding elements via jquery

Comment: actually it is setting the property of checked to false, but for some reason the checkbox isnt being unchecked. testing in chrome

Comment: how are you loading your checkboxes. and maybe try it in another browser

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same class for all your checkboxs and then use in your function :

```
checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
var n=checkboxes.length;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = false;
}
```

Hope it helps